# Webkit and Excel file(PHPexcel)

Tags: php, excel, zend-framework

I have an excel file which can be downloaded..for example NAME.xlsx well it works in firefox but in webkit(safari/chrome) it appends to the name also **the extension .xhtml** so then name it will be NAME.xlsx.html it should be **ONLY .xlsx**

Here you have my headers:

```
            $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

        $objWriter->save($root.'/application/to_excel/KSW.xlsx');
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/download', true); 
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream', true);            
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', true);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment;filename='.basename($root.'/application/to_excel/KSW.xlsx').'', true);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0', true);
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting `content-type` thrice? Can you try using the `octet-stream` one only?

Comment: Now it only adds to the name (1).html..before was .xhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not had this function fail yet -- it works with all the Office 2007/2010 files that I've tried so far in Safari (Windows) and Chrome.  The get_known_mime_types() function just returns a giant array of all the mime-types that my app supports -- just Google for the MIME types you need.  `$file` is the actual path to the file on your host, and `$name` is the file name that displays in the download (run/save) dialog.  I've also given due credit to the place I got most of it from.  Hope you have luck with it too:

```
function file_download($file, $name, $mime_type='') {
    /* The majority of this code was taken from:
     * http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/
     * 
     * So a big thanks to them.
     * I have modified parts of it, though, so it's not 100% borrowed.
     */

    if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

    $size = filesize($file);
    $name = rawurldecode($name);

    /* Figure out the MIME type (if not specified) */
    $known_mime_types = get_known_mime_types();

    if($mime_type==''){
        $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));

        if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
            $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
        } else {
            $mime_type="application/force-download";
        }
    }

    @ob_end_clean(); //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage

    // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    }

    header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    /* The three lines below basically make the download non-cacheable */
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header('Pragma: private');
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    // multipart-download and download resuming support
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
        list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
        list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
        $range=intval($range);

        if(!$range_end) {
            $range_end=$size-1;
        } else {
            $range_end=intval($range_end);
        }

        $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;

        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
        header("Content-Length: $new_length");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
    } else {
        $new_length=$size;
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
    }

    /* output the file itself */
    $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // 1MB, can be tweaked if needed
    $bytes_send = 0;

    if ($file = fopen($file, 'r')) {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
            fseek($file, $range);
        }

        while(!feof($file) && (!connection_aborted()) && ($bytes_send<$new_length)) {
            $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
            print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // is also possible
            flush();
            $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
        }

        fclose($file);
    } else {
        die('Error - can not open file.');
    }

    die();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome -- it took me at least two months to find that article and then make the rest of it work.  I'm happy to share that wealth.