# Force Browser to download Image with Javascript window.open?

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to make an image a download once you click on it (without right-click *save image as*)?

I'm using a small Javascript function to call the download page:

```
<a href="#" 
   onclick="window.open('download.php?file=test.jpg', 'download', 'status=0');"
>Click to download</a>
```

In the download.php page I have something like:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$file."");
readfile($file);
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that, with this code, anyone can download any possible file from your server : just specific the path to any file in the URL, and voila, you get its content...

Comment: @Pascal; Don't worry, it's secured, this is just a small part of the code

Comment: Maybe there are PHP error in your download.php but In the above code is correct and it is working. I have tested :) You can test by writing exit before header.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [*application/octet-stream*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1) instead of *image/jpg*:

> If [the Content-Disposition] header is used in a response with the application/octet-stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.
> — [RFC 2616 – 19.5.1 Content-Disposition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.5.1)

Comment: Its saved as a jpg, and the filename is correct. But when I open the file it's damaged? So it seems like it isn't actualy a jpeg

Comment: @Jay Wit: You probably send more data than just the file’s contents (like some whitespace etc.).

Comment: @Gumbo; Some filenames/directories contain whitespaces yes, but is that a problem?

Comment: @Jay Wit: I meant that you probably not just send the file’s contents but also some other data that was put out earlier (like whitespace, HTML markup, etc.).

Comment: @Gumbo; Oh no, even if I change `$file = "test.jpg"` it still downloads a damaged jpeg

Comment: @Jay Wit: It’s `readfile` that prints the file’s contents. Just use a hex editor to see the actual data that has been sent.

Comment: @Gumbo; Hex editor? How does it work?  And any other idea on what might went wrong?

Comment: @Jay Wit: A hex editor lets you see and edit the value of each byte in hexadecimal notation. Then you can see what actually has been sent.

Comment: @Gumbo; Yup, now I see what goes wrong. The imagefile contains the text of the download.php page. So it downloads the page, and converts it to a jpeg with the filename. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @Jay Wit: Just don’t do any output except with `readfile` or buffer it so that it doesn’t get sent to the client.

Comment: @Gumbo; I removed al the text of the page, but the image file still contain's one whitespace(enter), if I remove that one it works perfect. But I don't know what generates the white space...

Comment: @Gumbo; Nevermind, the whitespace was created by the `<script>[tab]window.close();</script>`. Removed the tab and it worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I think you forgot to add Path on the header

```
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    //Please give the Path like this
    $file = 'images/'.$_GET['file'];

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use .htaccess file for all your image files. In case you want to force the browser to download all your images (f.e. from a table list):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^download$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .(jpe?g|gif|png)$ index.php?file=noFoundFilePage [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^download$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .(jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L,NC,T=application/octet-stream]
```

This looks for image files a tries to force download them into the browser. The -f RewriteConds also checks that the file exsist.. The last rule ensures that download is used only for certain file types.

Comment: Thanks :-) I like it the most too ;-) It is clean and without using PHP as a stream.. Just for chosen dir. Alas it does not suit every use case..

Comment: To get this to work for JPGs in IE 9, I had to add `Header set Content-Disposition attachment` to the Apache configuration as well.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
header("Pragma: public");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$title);
header("Content-type: ".mime_content_type($sample_file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
readfile($sample_file);
```

I also added the following to .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.jpg$" requested_jpg=jpg
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_jpg
```

Not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on an apache server this is really simple.

1. Create a file called .htaccess in the directory in which your files exist. For me it was `assets/.htaccess`.
2. Add the following to the file `AddType application/octet-stream .jpg`. You can add a new line for each file extension that you need. E.g. `AddType application/octet-stream .pdf`
3. Save your file
4. **Clear your browser cache**
5. Refresh your browser and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Once you’ve added the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, you should be able to use a normal link:

```
<a href="download.php?file=test.jpg">Click to download</a>
```

What browsers have you tried this with?

Comment: It keeps downloading the page itself, am I doing something wrong? I've tried this in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @JayWit: Does it download the PHP code?  If so, your web server is configured to _not_ run PHP scripts in that directory.  What server are you using?  If it doesn’t download the PHP code, then what _does_ it download?

Comment: It downloads a damaged jpeg file, I think an empty file with just the filetype jpg. Not sure though. Any ideas?

Comment: Open that downloaded .jpg file using Notepad.exe; what do you see then?

Answer (score 1):

This is a button you can click on in internet explorer to download pic

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form><input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="window.location.href='image.jpg'"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers recognize jpg `URL's` and hand them over just like a .htm, so I don't think you can force it on the user-end (not positive on that, though).

Read this

http://apptools.com/phptools/force-download.php

Comment: They recognize headers. If none ar preset, they look at the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$file."");
```

To:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ".$file);
```

If the above doesn't work to you, here a function to force a file to be downloadable:

```
    <?php
function downloadFile($file, $type)
{
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
}

    downloadFile("sd.jpg", "image/jpg");
    ?>
```

Comment: I updated my code, its work for me now, just make sure you are pointing to existing file.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I have an image `sd.jpg` right next to my download.php file and it's still a damaged jpeg. Could this problem be because I'm on my localhost?

Comment: I am also in localhost, try to clear browser cache, also try another image.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

[Webkit and Excel file(PHPexcel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019068/webkit-and-excel-filephpexcel/3019179#3019179)

Comment: This worked just fine for me.  How did you use it?  I used your download link verbatim, a jpg named test.jpg, and my function.  http://pastebin.com/xPkS9NhU

Comment: Side note: the jpg is in the same file path as the download.php script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to force all files in a certain directory to be prompted for a download.

**Requirement**

1. Apache
2. [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) enabled

In your .htaccess or Apache configuration put the following.

```
<Directory /path/to/downloadable/files>
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
</Directory>
```