# How do I make a jpg image download like a pdf file does?

Tags: jquery, download

I have a request to make a jpg image download in the same way a pdf file would.

At present if I add a jpg image to a web page as a link, it will open in another browser window rather than actually download to the users computer. However, a pdf file will.

Here is the standard code:

```
<a href="/images/my-image.jpg">download image</a>
```

I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to modify your webserver configuration or write a script modifying the header when the file is sent to the browser. Browsers will always try to display images.

Comment: Are you using any server-side language?  If so, one way I can think of is to use the content-disposition header.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012437/uses-of-content-disposition-in-an-http-response-header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PHP on the server you can do this.

```
<?php 
// Force download of image file specified in URL query string and which 
// is in the same directory as this script: 
if(!empty($_GET['img'])) 
{ 
   $filename = basename($_GET['img']); // don't accept other directories 
   $size = @getimagesize($filename); 
   $fp = @fopen($filename, "rb"); 
   if ($size && $fp) 
   { 
      header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}"); 
      header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename)); 
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
      fpassthru($fp); 
      exit; 
   } 
} 
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
?>
```

HTML Would then look like this

```
<img src="/images/download.php?img=imagename.jpg" alt="test">
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to set your web server, or a server-side script (php, asp.net, etc) to serve your jpg file with **[the Content-Disposition header](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html)** :

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-image.jpg"
```

Script:

- [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648967/force-download-image)
- [ASP.NET](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/how_to_force_a_file_to_download_in_aspnet.aspx)

Servers:

- [Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files)
- [IIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/31207/force-png-to-download-instead-of-opening-in-browser-with-iis)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the suggestion mentioned here:
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080417163416AAjlb7T

It would look something like this:

```
access_file.php:

<?php

$f= $_GET['file'];

$filename = explode("/", $f);
$filename = $filename[(count($filename)-1)];

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
readfile($f);

?>
```

If you stick the access_file.php file in your images folder then you could just use the link:

```
<a href="/images/access_file.php?file=my-image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

How PDF content type opens from your browser is determined by a number of different settings.  It could be influenced by content type associations to a program in your browser settings.  It also may be influenced by settings in the PDF reader itself, for instance, Adobe Reader under **Edit**, **Preferences...**, **Internet** tab has an option for if PDF documents should open in the browser or in the application directly.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5 we have an attribute called download

```
<a href="img/myimage.jpg" download="myimage.jpg"><img src="img/myimage.jpg" /></a>
```