# How to save barcode image to folder in drive of computer?

Tags: php

I've created a barcode using the PHP barcode plugin

HTML

```
<img src="barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321" style="width:auto; height:auto;" alt="123456789"/>
```

How can I save this barcode image to my local drive hard drive?

Comment: Please post your `barcode` creation code to better understanding.

Comment: Right click -> Save to disk? What are you asking? What you actually looked inside `barcode.php`?

Comment: uh......sorry i mean how to save barcode image auto when page load.

Comment: A website cannot directly write something to the user's local disk, thank god!

Comment: deceze, i mean write in server

Comment: maybe you can add a header upon execution in php something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/12048002/1978142

Comment: This should help you: http://uk3.php.net/imagepng

Comment: @kevinabelita, i try already, but can have other way that can save image auto without alert save message and click save button?

Answer (score -1):

Try this get the content and save it to file

```
$barcode = file_get_contents('http://www.youdomain.com/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321');

//you can also use below function get more info on image 
//$imgInfo = getimagesize($barcode);

//save the file to disk 
file_put_contents('path_to_file/code.png', $barcode);
```

**Use CURL**

```
//You can also try it using CURL if above doesn't works

$ch = curl_init('http://www.youdomain.com/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321');
$fp = fopen('path_to_file/code.png', 'wb');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

**Edit barcode.php**

Now its very simple, as in file its simply returning header of image, right before you can add this line to save it on server

```
// Save the image to file.png
imagepng($image, "file.png"); // Your barcode will be saved here with name file.png

// Draw barcode to the screen
header ('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: my purpose is want to save image automatic to disk, do not need alert message save box. Warning: file_get_contents(barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\SVN\roadTax\doc.php on line 12

Comment: path of barcode.php is not correct, try absolute path and it should work

Comment: I am sure path of barcode.php is correct because it's stay in the same root.

Comment: use your absolute url of barcode.php like this `file_get_contents('http://www.youdomain.com/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321');`

Comment: I still get this error Warning: file_put_contents(http://localhost/SVN/roadTax/code.jpg) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in D:\wamp\www\SVN\roadTax\doc.php on line 34.

Comment: This is code:  <?php
$barcode = file_get_contents('http://localhost/SVN/roadTax/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321');

file_put_contents('http://localhost/SVN/roadTax/code.jpg', $barcode);

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/SVN/roadTax/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321');
$fp = fopen('path_to_file/code.jpg', 'wb');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>

Comment: would you post the barcode.php in http://pastebin.com/ and send me the link, or share the barcode.php library link.

Comment: I am doing in local machine now. can how i share you the barcode.php? I think in this very difficult to share you. this is my skype: toeurtenh1. i want to share wity you by skype is easy then.

Comment: Edit barcode.php? I am not well understand what you mean

Comment: open barcode.php and add `imagepng($image, "file.png"); ` as shown in answer

Comment: editing barcode.php is simple, you just need to add one line of code and you are done. open it and scroll down just put `imagepng($image, "code.png");` before `// Draw barcode to the screen` that's all

Comment: ok already add imagepng($image, "code.png"); to barcode.php, how about this codes? $ch = curl_init('http://www.youdomain.com/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321');
$fp = fopen('path_to_file/code.png', 'wb');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

Comment: is it working, did you get a file in same folder named `code.png`

Comment: i get this error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in D:\wamp\www\SVN\roadTax\doc.php on line 16

Comment: this is my update code: $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/SVN/roadTax/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=50&text=123421321321321321');
$fp = fopen('http://localhost/SVN/roadTax/code.png', 'wb');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

Comment: you dont have curl library installed. editing barcode.php is simplest way but i dont know why you are not listening

Comment: Ok now i get barcode image to my disk. thank you so much Mr. Saqueib.

Comment: Can you help me one more problem? I can not post my question in here that why i want to ask you by comment:  How can i conver div content to doc file in my disk?

Comment: Currently i used PHP header like this:  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=FILENAME.doc");     but not auto save in to my directory disk. How can i do?

Comment: you can use this library http://www.phpdocx.com/, please accept the answer if it solved.

Comment: it's not free for using

Comment: try this http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/html-to-doc-classes/html-to-doc-classes/html_to_doc.inc.php

Comment: after run codes in http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/html-to-doc-classes/html-to-doc-classes/html_to_doc.inc.php, nothing happen , why?