# Downloading Canvas element to an image

Tags: javascript, canvas, download

What are the different ways to save a canvas object?

In my research, I've found two approaches:

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL();
var prev = window.location.href;
window.location.href = data.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
window.location.href = prev;
```

Another way is to take a snapshot.

Are there other ways to do this?

Is it possible to customize the download filename?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The one way to save is exporting as an image... You already found this solution, and it's the best one i think ;)

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

You can use different image types. Change the mimetype in this function:

```
    canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

An other way to save canvas data (into a PDF) is using the [wkhtmltopdf Library](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Cheers. Frank

frankneff.ch / @frankneff

Comment: When I do document.write, wouldn't it just write onto the webpage? Or would that issue a download command?

Comment: Yes it just writes the image onto the page. You can force downloading, but in that case, you'll need a server-side implementation [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648967/force-download-image), or google "force image download"

Comment: to download the image you can place it in an ```<a>``` tag using ```download``` attribute (html5) : ```<a href="javascript:canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');" download="download" >Download as jpeg</a>```

Answer (score 116):

Solution that requires **NO BUTTON**:

```
var download = function(){
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'filename.png';
  link.href = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL()
  link.click();
}
```

Useful if you have other triggers for downloading, or triggers that you can't easily reference.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI can you be more specific? And in case you found a fix, share it.

Comment: check the answer , actually toDataURL is not longer effective due to security reason but if you are downloading the image from canvas that was imported from img tag then this tag should have crossorigin attribute to make it work see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424279/canvas-todataurl-securityerror

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI thanks! can you check if implementing the suggested answer (img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.src = url) works?

Answer (score 32):

```js
function download() {
var download = document.getElementById("download");
var image = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png")
    .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
download.setAttribute("href", image);
//download.setAttribute("download","archive.png");
}
```

```html
<a id="download" download="triangle.png">
<button type="button" onClick="download()">Download</button>
</a>
    
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="720" height="450">Your browser does not support Canvas.</canvas>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better?

Comment: Yeah, why? Sorry, I can't edit it! The queue is full

Answer (score 21):

Try something like this...

```
function downloadCanvasAsImage(){

    let canvasImage = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL('image/png');
    
    // this can be used to download any image from webpage to local disk
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        a.download = 'image_name.png';
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
      };
      xhr.open('GET', canvasImage); // This is to download the canvas Image
      xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: What if we want to convert it in SVG? Please guide.

Comment: Canvas is a raster format. SVG is a vector format. You can't just convert between them

Answer (score 9):

```
var c = document.getElementById("popup");
var link = document.getElementById('cropImageLink');
link.setAttribute('download', 'MintyPaper.png');
link.setAttribute('href', c.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"));
link.click();
```

I hope these code would be work. But first create Anchor tag in canvas tag whose id is 'cropImageLink'. than after check. but it's not working in IE browser

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [reimg](http://github.com/gillyb/reimg) library to do this really easily.

Converting the canvas to an img :
`ReImg.fromCanvas(document.getElementById('yourCanvas')).toPng()`

And downloading this image for the user can be done like this :
`ReImg.fromCanvas(document.getElementById('canvas')).downloadPng()`

About giving the file a custom name, if you look into the code of the library (which is **very** short and simple to understand) you'll find that you can change the name.

Here is a link to the specific line: https://github.com/gillyb/reimg/blob/master/reimg.js#L63
`filename = filename || 'image.png';`

Answer (score 0):

relate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135417/download-canvas-as-png-in-fabric-js-giving-network-error/59835941#59835941) and thanks to @kaiido

I just modified the callback method and it worked ,the callback method mentioned there was not working for me

```
var callback = function(blob) {
var a = document.createElement('a');
var saveAs = $('input[name="group1"]:checked').val();


var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'Image.' + saveAs;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();

};
 function dataURIToBlob(dataURI, callback) {
var binStr = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]),
len = binStr.length,
arr = new Uint8Array(len);

 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
 }

   callback(new Blob([arr]));
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Chromium DevTools > Inspect canvas tag > **'Capture node screenshot'** and and you can paste it anywhere for a simple and quick review.

[image: Capture node screenshot]

Comment: This creates a screenshot, doesn't download the canvas element