# How to instantiate controller in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use Angular with non-DOM view (using Pixi.js), so I need to instantiate controller manually (analogical to ng-controller attribute), I found something like:

```
$controller('MyController', {$scope: $scope}));
```

but it suppose I have already $scope created.

Note: I know Angular is mainly aimed to use DOM element, but for Pixi, it could be a little bit similar, I would use $watch and $apply for attributes like x, y, alpha etc.
Thanks.

Comment: `angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){})`

Comment: Angular's concept of scope is integrally tied to the DOM — see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587961/is-there-already-a-canvas-drawing-directive-for-angularjs-out-there for a tangential discussion around dealing with canvas in an Angular way

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is like this:

```
angular.module('<module-name>', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to create a "definition" of controller, but an instance.

Comment: Like [Mark Fox said in his comment](#comment-43644891), Angular's scope is tied to the DOM, so without it you can't instantiate a controller.