# How to call Canvas LMS API in AngularJS and handle it in controller?

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain

Can anybody help me with this ? 
i want to call course list canvas API in angularJS.

if you have any sample or example then please share with me.

API references : [Canvas API](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/courses.html)

thanks

Comment: Do refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587961/is-there-already-a-canvas-drawing-directive-for-angularjs-out-there

Comment: thanks.. i was asking about Canvas LMS API ...  not about canvas .