# How to save canvas as an image in html5?

Tags: html

How to save canvas as an image in html5(using javascript)? I want to create a button   such that user can save canvas in html5 as image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Save Canvas As An Image With canvas.toDataURL()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl)