# Data url to image to submit

Tags: javascript, canvas, jpeg, submit-button, todataurl

Currently I have a canvas.todataurl which I have turned into a jpeg.
I wouldn like the user of my website to be able to save the image and then use it for a submit button. Any suggestions on how I could do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl

Comment: i have already got the dataurl as an image now i need to save it to desktop or something and then use it in a submit button