# Draw a rectangle on an image in servlet

Tags: html, jsp, html5-canvas

Here is my problem :

I have to draw rectangles on images and control everything by a website with jsp pages. I have no idea how can I show the image on the jsp and on click draw a rectangle on it and save it.

I wanted to do it with javascript but if we reload the page all the changes won't be applied.

My application run with JEE, hibernate, spring.

Thank's

Comment: TO draw shapes on html page you can use [javascript canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) and save it as image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685544/6743203)

Comment: Oh, thank's that's what i'm looking for !