# how to get screenshot of gltf model in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aframe, gltf, ar.js

I'm making AR web app using AR.js and React.
It renders the 3D model using `<a-gltf-model>` component by A-Frame because AR.js is related with A-Frame.

I'd like to make a function to save favorite 3D `models(gltf models)` as screenshots.

how to get screenshot of gltf model in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the current state of A-Frame's `<canvas>` element to an image. See [How To Save Canvas As An Image With canvas.toDataURL()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl), or (in the easiest case) as below:

```
var canvas = sceneEl.canvas;

// here is the most important part because if you dont replace you will get a DOM 18 exception.
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");  

window.location.href=image; // it will save locally
```

Comment: i have solved by the method `document.querySelector('a-scene').components.screenshot.getCanvas('equirectangular')` but your answer is really helpful for me to know how to save canvas as an image! thanks a lot :)