# HTML5, JS: take a pic with cam and save it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to take a pic with my browser and to save it in my disc.
In this link https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera i found how to take a pic,it is very easy but i can't save it.

Comment: To my knowledge, the browser only allows you to save files to a very specific limited space, that is some local folder in the temp app fodler whatnot. This would not be good for you. What i suggest you do is "download" the image instead. Google how to do that. It would allow you to save it where you want

Comment: What you are looking for is how to download you canvas image. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685544/10004860

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Navigator.getUserMedia()` 
It prompts the user for permission to use up to one video input device (such as a camera or shared screen).

`navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);`

For further reference you can refer [THIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) documentation.