# How to read InkML file to image or text using C#

Tags: xml, microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, inkml

I am trying to read handwritten text in onenote from the APIs provided by microsoft. I am able to get the handwritten text from onenote as inkML. Unfortunately I am unable to read from the inkML to image/text.Please suggest some solutions or links that can help me.

I need library or package that will help me with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OneNote API supports getting InkML in beta: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/onenote-ink-beta-apis/

The you can use InkMLJs to render it to a canvas: https://github.com/Microsoft/InkMLjs

Once you have it in a canvas, you can export to an image 
[How To Save Canvas As An Image With canvas.toDataURL()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl)

As for the “extracting text” part… OneNote API does not support getting the ink analysis text from the OneNote page, so you'd have to run the analysis yourself via the coordinates in the InkML.

Comment: Hi @Jorge Aguirre,

I am now able to get the Image through the canvas many thanks for this guide. 

What I need help from you is, I am getting all this operations done in the index page of an angular application. Is there a way that I can do the same in component level?
Secondly, I came across an experimental package  https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-ink-analysis from Microsoft on ink analysis, how can I use this in my project to read/extract the ink strokes? Can you please extend some help on this.

Comment: Hi Jorge, 
I am unable to get any response from the below Vision API for handwritten text
https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/recognizeText?mode=Handwritten

Please check and let me know

Comment: This is unrelated to the original question. Please ask a new question. Also, I am not familiar with this package.