# how to save editable image using canvas in angular

Tags: angular, canvas, fabricjs

i am new on canvas, i am working on an angular where user loads an image from local and resize image and also save resized image in local. please guide me. image load on canvas is done but 2nd part to save edited or resized image remains.
HTML code

```
  <input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleDrop($event)" />

<br />

<hr />

<canvas
id="canvasID"
width="720"
height="480"
style="border: 1px solid red"
></canvas>
```

ts code

```
ngOnInit() {
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasID', { fireRightClick: true });
   }
handleDrop(e:any) {
// this.file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
this.file = e.target.files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
this.angularFireStorage.upload("/files"+Math.random(), this.file)
reader.onload = (imgFile:any) => {
  console.log(imgFile);
  const data = imgFile.target["result"];
  fabric.Image.fromURL(data, (img) => {
    let oImg = img.set({
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      angle: 0
    }).scale(1);
  this.canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
  var a = this.canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
  var dataURL = this.canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
  console.log(dataURL);

  });
};
reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
return false;
 }
```

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869638/2247541

Comment: this is not working in my case.

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: no, but not saving image.

Comment: You can prepare small demo with https://stackblitz.com/ and then edit your question may be someone can find out issue.