# Does HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() make an additional request to the server?

Tags: javascript, browser, todataurl

I am a Javascript beginner and sorry if my question is odd. I am asking about a situation where the following is done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69841002/14819077

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why would you expect that?

Comment: I thought it probably doesn't, but I couldn't find anything that clearly stated it, so I asked the question. Thanks.

Comment: Notice, that the canvas is aware of [a cross-origin image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), even without checking that from the server.

Comment: If they were gonna describe all the things something _doesn't do_ we would be here all day.