# Variable is not defined outside of the function

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, jotform

Can someone please help me with this? I am new and I debugged and tried several codes while executing my codes. I'm trying to pass a base64string into JotForms that will allow me to generate my image into their PDF.
Here is my the error screenshot.
[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM6fG.png)

And this is the code I am having trouble with, this is my function.

```
 function screenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        scrollY: -window.scrollY,
        crossOrigin : 'Anonymous',
        allowTaint: true,
        foreignObjectRendering: true, 
    }).then(function (canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        var data0101 = document.body.appendChild(canvas).toDataURL();
        console.log('Result', data0101)
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    });
}
```

and this is the JotForm code that is outside the function,

```
var myImage = data0101;
console.log(myImage)
var submissionData = {
    valid: true,
    value: JFCustomWidgetUtils.buildMetadata('imagelinks', [{
        'name': "Data from Widget",
        'base64': myImage
    }])
}
JFCustomWidget.subscribe('ready', function (data333333) {
    console.log("ready message arrived from JotForm", data333333);
    JFCustomWidget.sendData(submissionData);//Do this as soon as your image is ready
    JFCustomWidget.sendsubmit(submissionData);//This will run when the submit button is clicked
});
```

Thank you so much

Comment: You would have to make the variable global or the value accessable globally or put the functionality that relies on it in the same scope. One way would be using `window.data0101 = ` instead of `var data0101 =`.

Comment: Hello @JavaScript, it is still undefined under the code, var myImage = data0101; and when changing it also to window.data0101, the console says it is undefined

Comment: That suggests you calling the second part of the posted code before the first one is finished. Why not just add the second part below `document.body.removeChild(canvas);` inside the `then` block?

Comment: Hello @JavaScript, i tried it but it seems when pasting it inside it do not work

Answer (score 0):

You declare your **data0101** variable inside the funcion. This means you can only use it inside your function. Once you leave this function, this variable no longer available. Thats why you are getting this error.

To solve this you can declare you variable before this function as a global variable. Something like:

```
 var data0101 = null;
 function screenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        scrollY: -window.scrollY,
        crossOrigin : 'Anonymous',
        allowTaint: true,
        foreignObjectRendering: true, 
    }).then(function (canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        data0101 = document.body.appendChild(canvas).toDataURL();
        console.log('Result', data0101)
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    });
```

Comment: Hello @Frigyes, when I tried it outside the function on myImage, and doing console.log it says null, it do not get the base64string

Comment: Hello @Frigyes, when I tried it outside the function on myImage, and doing console.log it says null, it do not get the base64string

Comment: @RottenPotatoes You can use a second variable, but no you cannot use any variable if it is not in the same parent block of code. You use data0101 inside your code, you can't use it globally.

Comment: Hello @KOMODO, is there a possible way to get this data0101 = document.body.appendChild(canvas).toDataURL();? and insert it outside the function?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do? you can send data0101 to any function as parameter.

Comment: Hello @KOMODO, in my second line of code with var myImage = data0101, it is reading as null because var data0101 = null; right? But i want that myImage to be what is inside here, data0101 = document.body.appendChild(canvas).toDataURL();

Comment: Where do you call your **screenshot()** function? The order is very important.
`var data0101 = null;`
`screenshot();`
`var myImage = data0101;`

Also can you tell me what `document.body.appendChild(canvas).toDataURL();` gives back? Can you log it to me? It seems wrong.

Comment: Hello @Frigyes, this code document.body.appendChild(canvas).toDataURL(); it converts the image jpeg or png to base64strings, Even doing the orders, it still null.

Comment: It seems wrong to me. This should be `data0101=canvas.toDataURL();` Also you need to call your **screenshot()** function. Otherwise **data0101** will remain **null**. I already told you the right order.
Maybe this will help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl

Comment: because i have a trigger button that will screen capture the entire html, can i change it to data0101=canvas.toDataURL()? @FrigyesVass

Comment: @FrigyesVass i tried doing it, still it do not get what is inside data0101

Comment: Can you upload all the code here somehow?

Comment: @FrigyesVass here is the code link. 
tm7.net.au

Comment: Hello @FrigyesVass is there any way to do it?