# It's not possible to clone/copy/download my canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas element on my page. I convert it to png

```
 const canvas = document.getElementById("WebGLContainer") as HTMLCanvasElement;
 const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
```

and then I download or display the pic which is a transparent pic.

On the screenshot you can see the trophy (canvas element) which should transformed to png. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gVMW.png)

but the trophy is ignored and I can see only the green button and white background. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPC6A.png)

Even If I click at the canvas and press "save as" in google chrome it downloads just a grey image.

this is my html code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKBuA.png)

I tried to use domtoimage, htmltoimage packages, convert to blob.

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl

Comment: no it didn't help.