# File() constructor in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The File() constructor is not supported in IE and Safari.[CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=File)

Is there a nice solution to this in Angular/JavaScript?

```
var file = new File(byteArrays, tempfilename, { type: contentType });
```

Could I create the file in other ways, that is supported by IE an Safari?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly isn't supported or what solution you'd want to an unsupported feature.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi The File() constructor isent supported. The code above i falling because of that..

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want or need to use the File API, there's [mOxie polyfill](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie) suggested by [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=File).

Comment: What alternatives do I have? Without rewritting the complete program..

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the details of the problem you're solving

Comment: I "just" need to create a base64 file whit that type and filename. I creathe the file in a Base64ToFile converter. Called like this: base64ToFile(tempcroppedImage, 'tempfilename.jpg', 'image/jpeg');

Comment: Is there a good alternative to create a file with javascript?

Comment: Are you sure you really need a file? May be you can solve your actual higher-level problem with <canvas> and data: URL? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8126887/6430 As for the File, the polyfill is a good option. Something like that need to rely on a native browser extension like Flash, Java Applet, ActiveX and alike

Comment: I solved the problem today by creating a blob instead. FileReader is supported by all browsers.

Comment: @Deleteme: thanks! Blob to the rescue.

Comment: The mOxie polyfill is not available for commercial use without purchasing a licence.