# Is there an alternative for File() constructor for Safari and IE?

Tags: angularjs, file, internet-explorer, safari, filereader

I am using the File() constructor for creating file object for uploading a blob file to the server. The following code works fine for Chrome, but fails for Safari and Internet Explorer.

```
image_url = new File([blob],file_name,{type: mimeString});
```

The code is breaking at this line and getting this error in console "FileConstructor is not a constructor" (evaluating 'new File([blob],file_name,{type: mimeString})')

Using the FileReader API is an alternative to this but I am not able to fix this issue.

Comment: Hey @Johny me, I found that lot of people helped my answer, would you accept it as correct?

Comment: Yeah sure, thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I Suggest to use the blob api, I've found the same problem and I solved like that:

```
var html = <svg>whatever on svg </svg>
var fileName = "myfile.svg";
var blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'image/svg'});
blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
// var blobAttrs = {type: "image/svg"};
// var file = new File([html], fileName, blobAttrs);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file",blob,fileName);
```

It is not a "file", but you can use it like it was.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day!

Comment: 2 years later this saved me supporting ios 9.3.

Answer (score 4):

According to web "Can I use" Safari does not support the `new File()` constructor. See this link http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

So I think you have to either use FileReader or maybe use some of the polyfills listed here https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Especially this one could be useful for you https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI (I did not use it myself)

Also have a look at this SO answer [What to use instead of FileReader for Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734150/what-to-use-instead-of-filereader-for-safari)

Comment: Thanks!! let me give a try to these possible solutions.

Comment: Well I am using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload directive, and using the shim file and have mentioned the code as mentioned in the Cross-browser support part, but I am not able to upload a file on Safari.

Comment: Yes the same error "FileConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new File([blob],file_name,{type: mimeString})')"

Comment: The docs says `on demand flash FileAPI shim loading no extra load for html5 browsers.` so my guess is that perhaps you forgot to load/call that FileAPI shim?

Comment: `<script src="ng-file-upload-shim(.min).js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->`

Comment: 'ng-file-upload-shim.min.js' this is the file that I have included in the project

Comment: Yes I have included this file in my project.

Comment: Try call `new File()` in dev console. If it produces error, then the shim is probably not loaded. Also have a look at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727052/file-constructor-in-ie-and-safari

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6 classes:

```js
class CustomFile extends Blob
{
    constructor(blobParts, filename, options) {
        super(blobParts, options);
        this.name = filename || "";
        if(options) {
          this.lastModified = options.lastModified;
        }
    }

    lastModified = 0;
    name = "";
}
const blob = new Blob();
const fileObject = new CustomFile([blob],"myfile");

console.log(fileObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a File [ponyfill](https://ponyfill.com/) [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanker/file-ponyfill) which works with modern module imports. This makes usage simple but you do need to import it in every module where you use `new File()`.

```js
import File from '@tanker/file-ponyfill';

const myFile = new File(['somefiledata'], 'example.txt', { type: 'text/plain'});
```