# Angularjs 'FileConstructor is not a constructor'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

> Issue: Error: FileConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
>   File([blob], "filename.png")')

I saw this question [Alternative for File() constructor for safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821631/alternative-for-file-constructor-for-safari) but there weren't any alternatives worth looking at.

Is there anyway to work around this using Ionic Framework on IOS?

**Javascript**

a = Base64 image.

```
 var blob = new Blob([a], {type: 'image/png'});

        console.log(blob);
        $scope.Issue14 = blob;

       var nfile = new File([blob], "filename.png");

        console.log(nfile);
        $scope.Issue15 = nfile;

       var _file = nfile;

        console.log(_file);
        $scope.Issue16 =  _file;

        $scope.Images.push({"img": _file});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same issue with File and Safari. 
After some research I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript) that seems to work for me... hope it will be useful for you:

Instead of using ***new File***, i append *name* and *lastModifiedDate* fields to the blob.

```
 blob.name = "filename.png";
 blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
```

It is not a file, but you can use it like it was...