# React enzyme test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, blob, enzyme

My react component has a File input (upload) element.
When an `xlsx` file is uploaded by the user, a component method is called, which reads the `xlsx` file converts into JSON and puts it into the redux table. The method is "convertFileDataToJSON" which accepts the File
object and does the above.

**I need to test this method.**

I am not able to use "new File("file://path/to/file")". 
I get the following error

> TypeError: FileConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new File')

I am using "new Blob" to create a blob object and sending it to the
instance method to the instance method.

```
var myBlob = new Blob(["application_id,Statement " +
"Received Date,Statement Requested Date,"+
"1,10/10/70,10/10/70,10/10/70"+
"2,12/20/71,12/20/71,12/20/71"], {type : "text/plain"});
const json = component.instance().convertFileDataToJSON(myBlob);
```

Any help would be appreciated, in how to test this method.

Comment: Could you please specify the environment you are testing in? Node.js? Desktop or Mobile browser?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not an answer, but let me suggest you to change how you test your own code.

Testing imperatively a React Component method is more or less an anti-pattern — a bad thing. The reason is simple: a Component defines its public API as *props* and that’s the surface you should test against.

> **Note:** while component instance methods are actually exposed to parent components that have a reference to them, it is considered a bad practice.

A nicer approach would be to have a standalone function that can be tested in isolation:

```
export function convertFileDataToJSON(file) {
  return // ...
}
```

and you would test it (in Jest) as:

```
import { convertFileDataToJSON } from '../utils/somewhere';

const blob = new Blob(
  [
    "application_id,Statement " +
    "Received Date,Statement Requested Date,"+
    "1,10/10/70,10/10/70,10/10/70"+
    "2,12/20/71,12/20/71,12/20/71"
  ],
  {type : "text/plain"}
);

describe('XLSX to JSON', () => {
  it('Works on simple CSV files', () => {
    const data = convertFileDataToJSON(blob);

    expect(data).toMatch( ...something );
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "Pier Paolo Ramon". I made it a separate util function.  I am sure it is getting invoked. I am returning a promise from this function.
Now I have to pass a File Object to this convert function to get it converted. Blob appears to be not working. new File() gives error. 
```
I am kind of stuck here. 
And how do I console.log() the "data" from this function's return?
```
Thanks

Comment: How are you running your tests? Are they run in Node.js or in the browser?

Comment: I am new to test. I run "npm run test" from CL. It is enzyme. We use only "shallow" rendering. Never using "mount". Functions are tested with jasmine.createSpy(). I believe it uses PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0). Please let me know if this info is not enough.

Comment: You should definitely update your that info.

DId you have a look at this Q&A?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656569/angularjs-fileconstructor-is-not-a-constructor

Comment: I have a test that checks if some other method is called with a new blob object, however i get a reference error for "Blob" as it is a browser thing. How have you got around this in your Jest tests?