# Error Converting Base64 data to File using JavaScript on Internet Explorer(0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to convert base64 data to file using javascript on asp.net, but i am getting( 0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action) error on final stage while converting blob to file at final stage.

Here is my code:

```
function dataBaseURLtoFile(str) {
    // extract content type and base64 payload from original string
    var pos = str.indexOf(';base64,');
    var type = str.substring(5, pos);
    var b64 = str.substr(pos + 8);

    // decode base64
    var imageContent = atob(b64);

    // create an ArrayBuffer and a view (as unsigned 8-bit)
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(imageContent.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

    // fill the view, using the decoded base64
    for (var n = 0; n < imageContent.length; n++) {
        view[n] = imageContent.charCodeAt(n);
    }

    // convert ArrayBuffer to Blob
    var blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: type });

    //convert blob to file

    var file = new File([blob], "name", { type: "image/jpeg", });

    return file;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Base64 String to javascript file object like as from file input form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940290/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-javascript-file-object-like-as-from-file-input-f)

Comment: No, I am getting same error '0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action' also with this solution.

Comment: var block = strL.split(";");
// Get the content type of the image
var type = block[0].split(":")[1];// In this case "image/gif"
// you can al so assign 
// var type = 'base64';
var pos = str.replace('data:;base64,', '');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to check your code and found that issue is on line below.

```
 var file = new File([blob], "name", { type: "image/jpeg", });
```

IE and Edge browser does not supports the File() constructor.

[File.File() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

For IE and Edge browser you need to use any alternative way.

You can try to refer thread below may give you some helpful information about alternative ways.

[Is there an alternative for File() constructor for Safari and IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821631/is-there-an-alternative-for-file-constructor-for-safari-and-ie)