# Download chart as PNG format in React without overwriting the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, filesaver.js, recharts

I want to download a chart created with `recharts` as a png image. I made it work if I write on the DOM. I would like to download the image instead. This is what I have so far thanks to this post:

[Recharts component to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086005/recharts-component-to-png/56223127?noredirect=1#comment100914961_56223127)

I have a clickable element to download the png and a chart in a component:

```
return (
      <div>
        <h1
          onClick={() => this.handleDownload()}
        >
          Download chart
        </h1>
        <LineChart
          ref={(chart) => this.currentChart = chart}
          width={500}
          height={300}
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="name" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{ r: 8 }} />
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
        </LineChart>
      </div>

    )
```

Whenever I click, I generate a canvas. Once I have an image thanks to the canvas, I could just write it in the DOM:

```
svgToPng = (svg, width, height) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Set background to white
      ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

      let xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
      let dataUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(xml);
      let img = new Image(width, height);

      img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        let imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);

        resolve(imageData)
      }

      img.onerror = () => reject();

      img.src = dataUrl;
    });
  };

  handleDownload = async () => {
    const chart = this.currentChart
    let chartSVG = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(chart).children[0]

    const pngData = await this.svgToPng(chartSVG, 400, 500)
    document.write('<img src="'+pngData+'"/>') // <------
  }
```

I would like to download the image instead of appending it to the DOM.

I tried this approach:

```
to download the image you can place it in an <a> tag using download attribute (html5) : <a href="javascript:canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');" download="download" >Download as jpeg</a>
```

I placed an the a tag in the DOM:

```
<a href={aTag} download="download" >Download as jpeg</a>
```

where `aTag is`:

```
const aTag = `'javascript:${this.state.imageData}.toDataURL('image/jpeg');'`
```

Basically, in my component I set a state with the canvas object:

```
class DownloadChart extends React.Component {
  state = {
    imageData: ''
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.handleDownload()
  }
```

I got rid of the `document.write` instruction, so I just generate the canvas object, and append it to the `href` attribute, whenever the component is mounted

```
<a href={aTag} download="download" >Download as png</a>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the download of a png image? I couldn't make it work with none of the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the extra quotes in `aTag`.

i.e.

```
const aTag = `javascript:${this.state.imageData}.toDataURL('image/jpeg');`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find out how to accomplish this and this question had 95% of the solution I needed to finally make it work.

You can use [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to download the PNG.

In `handleDownload`, replace `document.write('<img src="'+pngData+'"/>')` with `FileSaver.saveAs(pngData, "test.png")`.

The download doesn't work inside the CodeSandbox, so you'll have to open the sandbox first, click "Open in New Window" in the upper right corner, and then try the download:

[image: Edit focused-haze-vmhzg]