# toDataURL Image download has no extension

Tags: html, html5-canvas, todataurl

I am downloading an image when a div is clicked by using...

```
document.location.href = save_canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
```

This is working but the image that downloads has no extension and is just called 'download'

I have tried setting the name like this...

```
document.location.download = "myfile.jpg";
document.location.href = save_canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
```

But it is having no effect, where am i going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796513/html5-canvas-to-png-file

Answer (score 1):

The `download` attribute is not part of the [Location](https://devdocs.io/dom/location) object as [`document.location`](https://devdocs.io/dom/document/location) holds, only for the HTML anchor (A) tags (except in IE).

Depending on browser and version you could instead try to convert canvas into a `Blob` object, then to `File` in order to set a filename, and serve that as URL via `URL.createObjectURL()`. Also here, `toBlob()` is not supported in IE (but you can [polyfill](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob) `toBlob()`, and use [`msSaveBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx) instead).

(and you would also want to replace mime-type's "image" with "application" for mime-type (e.g. "application/octet-stream"). )

```js
c.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var file = new File([blob], "test.png", {type: "application/octet-stream"});
  document.location.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
})
```

```html
A save request with PNG and filename should appear when running this code...
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Optionally, try the [FileSaver.js library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which deals with many special cases.

Comment: The name and extension of png is not saved, only a random name without file extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185896/4906752