# from canvas.toDataURL() to download the image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to download the image from a canvas tag. I get from `var image = canvas.toDataURL()` base64, and thought that this could be used to create a `<a>` tag, and adding inside the tag `download = "image.png"` and `href = img` and simulate a click. I've googled around, but didn't find quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading Canvas element to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126623/downloading-canvas-element-to-an-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer actually to this question, lol.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'images.jpg';
link.download = 'Download.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```