# (Closed) How can I download canvas as png?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The HTML page I try to do is to upload image to canvas, put a watermark on that image, then download the image with the watermark as one png file. The current problem is I can upload the image to the canvas and put the watermark but I can't download the canvas.

I've already tried some solution on the internet including stackoverflow. Fidesaver.js didn't works for that. so here is the code:(The watermark in the code is just random 240x240 image i found in google)

The project page on Glitch.com seems not work anymore, so I put the code in the code snippet:

```html
Upper image:<br>
<img src="https://micolsalomone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/preloader-logo-240x240.png" width="150px" alt="Example image" id="wm" >
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/><br>
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var wm=document.getElementById("wm");
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function handleImage(e){ 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = '';
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = 240;
            canvas.height = 240;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,240,240);
            ctx.drawImage(wm,0,0,240,240);
            
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: refer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126623/downloading-canvas-element-to-an-image/56185896#56185896

Comment: @SumanPatra where should the code insert in? I'm just started to learn Javascript and Canvas. I've already tried multiple ways and none of those worked. They will only create a blank png or just immediately download blank png once the html opened. If you have any ideas you can edit the project here : https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/1a65c154-7e29-449b-8ba4-d746a6a3120a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```js
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function handleImage(e){ 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = '*';
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = 240;
            canvas.height = 240;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,240,240);
            
            
            var wm = new Image();
            
            wm.crossOrigin = '*';
            
            wm.onload = function () {
              ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,240,240);
              
              var base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
            
              var fileToSave = new Image();
            
              fileToSave.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('img_div').appendChild(this);
              };
            
              fileToSave.src = base64;
            };
            
            wm.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/YGxjLZw.png';
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]); 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://micolsalomone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/preloader-logo-240x240.png" width="150px" alt="Example image" id="wm" >
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/><br>
<div>
  Canvas
  <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="img_div">
  Image png:
</div>
```

Note: I'd changed your water mark image with another image because of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) reason. But you can still use it on your localhost.

After applying *water mark* to the canvas, you need to convert the canvas to image as `base64` string.

Then, you can parse the string to `Image` element. Now you can do everything with that element: download, append, apply to another canvas....