# How to save image from html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using html2canvas to convert the div into an image. To save the image I have to go right-click and save it. Is it possible to download the image without right-clicking?

I tried like :

```
<a href="<canvas style='width: 1903px; height: 886px;' width='1903' height='886'></canvas>">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

but it doesnt work.

```
<div id="output">
   <canvas style="width: 1903px; height: 886px;" width="1903" height="886"></canvas>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: as you so rightly "tagged" the question with `javascript` - you will need javsacript to do so - a little research (about 3 seconds worth), I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126623/downloading-canvas-element-to-an-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652379/9855409 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756191/9855409

I think you need just to select the canvas and save it as an image, you can't download it because it is not an image yet.