# Capturing An Image From The Computer's Camera And Saving It

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to capture an image of someone with the computer's camera, save it as a PNG image, and then send it to a view function in the Django framework.

I have found some source code for this at the following link:
https://www.studytonight.com/post/capture-photo-using-webcam-in-javascript

The following source code is what I have so far:

```
    <!doctype html>
    
    <head>
        <style>
        #video {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 320px;
            height: 240px;
        }
    
        #photo {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 320px;
            height: 240px;
        }
    
        #canvas {
            display: none;
        }
    
        .camera {
            width: 340px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    
        .output {
            width: 340px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    
        #startbutton {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            bottom: 36px;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: #6a67ce;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            font-size: 14px;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        .contentarea {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: Arial;
            text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
        <!--The title of the HTML document.-->
        <title>Facial Image Recognition</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="contentarea">
            <h1>Facial Image Recognition</h1>
    
            <div class="camera">
                <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
            </div>
            <!--An id on a <button> tag assigns an identifier to the button.
                The id allows JavaScript to easily access the <button> element
                and manipulate it.
                When a user clicks on the "Capture Image" button, the -->
            <div><button id="startbutton">Capture Image</button></div>
            
            <!-- <div>
            <a href="{% url 'facial-login-result' %}" id="startButton" 
               class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>Capture Image
            </a>
            </div> -->
    
            <!--The HTML canvas tag is where the image frames are stored
                before they are converted into an image of proper format
                to be shown using the <img> tag.-->
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    
            <div class="output">
                <img id="photo" alt="The image captured will appear in this box.">
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <script>
    
        (function() {
    
            // We will scale the photo width to this.
            var width = 320;
            // The height will be computed based on the input stream.
            var height = 0;
    
            var streaming = false;
    
            var video = null;
            var canvas = null;
            var photo = null;
            var startbutton = null;
    
            function startup() {
                video = document.getElementById('video');
                canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                photo = document.getElementById('photo');
    
                /*The following line is executed when a user clicks on the
                  "Capture Image" button.
                  
                  document.getElementById returns the element whose 'id'
                  is 'startbutton'.*/
                startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');
    
                // Access the video stream from the webcam.
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: false
                })
                // Upon success, stream video in a video tag.
                .then(function(stream) {
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
                });
    
                video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
                    if (!streaming) {
                        height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);
    
                        if (isNaN(height)) {
                            height = width / (4 / 3);
                        }
    
                        video.setAttribute('width', width);
                        video.setAttribute('height', height);
                        canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                        canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                        streaming = true;
                    }
                }, false);
    
                startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
                    takepicture();
                    ev.preventDefault();
                }, false);
    
                clearphoto();
            }
    
            /*Collect the frames of the photo from the canvas and then
              convert it into a PNG format, so that it can be shown in
              the HTML page.*/
            function clearphoto() {
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
                var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    
                photo.setAttribute('src', data);
            }
    
            /*Capture a frame from the video stream.*/
            function takepicture() {
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                if (width && height) {
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    
                    /*toDataURL('image/png') returns a data URL containing a
                      representation of the image in PNG format.*/
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    
                    /*'src' is the name of the attribute whose value is to be set.
                      'data' is a string containing the value to assign to the attribute.*/
                    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
                } else {
                    clearphoto();
                }
            }
    
            /*The following code will call the startup() function when
              the HTML page is loaded.*/
            window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
        })();
        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

My first question is where is the image that was captured from the computer's camera?

Was it assigned to the variable 'data' or was it assigned to the variable 'photo'?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let camera_button = document.querySelector("#start-camera");
let video = document.querySelector("#video");
let click_button = document.querySelector("#click-photo");
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

camera_button.addEventListener('click', async function() {
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    video.srcObject = stream;
});

click_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    // data url of the image
    console.log(image_data_url);
});
```

```html
<h2>Capture Photo From Camera using Javascript</h2>
<button id="start-camera">Start Camera</button>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
<button id="click-photo">Click Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the camera a stream is captured (if user agrees) and fed to the video input. Then, when you choose, the canvas takes snapshot of the video (`drawImage(video)`) and draws on itself. The same `<canvas>` has a method that converts itself to an image (or a DataURL of one). That data is fed as a src of the image element.

These are 3 of the magic lines.

```
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
photo.setAttribute('src', data);
```

If you want to store the image on the server, you can use the `data` string that is a base64 encoding of the image. Not efficient but it's a text. the `<img>` is not used for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. What if I wanted to download the image as a PNG file? How could I accomplish this?

Comment: You can right click on the `<img>` and save manually. Also right click on the `canvas` and Save as Image. So it makes sense you can be [Downloading Canvas element to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126623/downloading-canvas-element-to-an-image)

Comment: I mean how can I save the image with source code in JavaScript and HTML? Like have my program do it.

Comment: The link explains several ways to do so.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll have a look.