# how to save file from server that has no extension?

Tags: php, html

There is a file on server : `files/1`
Its name and extension is stored in a database. (For example: a.jpg)
Is it possible to download that file as `a.jpg` not as `1`? If yes, how?

In other words:

```
<a href='/files/1'>file</a>
```

should download file `1`'s content with the name `a.jpg`

Comment: "download" -- with what tool? `curl`? `wget`? a hand-written program?

Comment: from web using a link (and save as)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5649645/825789).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example from [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php):

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine, I have updated it with the example variables if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your question well, then:

HTaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ /getfile.php?fn=$1 [L]
```

Then getfile.php reads which file corresponds to $_GET["fn"] and outputs that.

Comment: So what should getfile.php contain?

Comment: It should have a database select where the pseudo file name is $_GET["fn"] so it gets the real one and then read the file and wcho it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. That way I have tested but it does not work.

Comment: Noo. `echo file_get_contents($result);` also the link isn't getfile?fn=1 but Pseudo-filename, which redirects to getfile.php via htaccess