# Force a Generated UPS Label to Download

Tags: php, ups

I'm using a third party php class to talk to UPS and generate a label. The generated label data comes in the Base64 format and I can display it like this.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.$label_data.'" />';
```

I'm just looking for a way to force this image to be downloaded (as a GIF) instead of just displaying it.

Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648967/force-download-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the data, just output the headers and then the data!

```
<?php
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header("Content-type: application/force-download"); // or application/octet-stream
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ups.gif"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: close');
echo $label_data;
exit;
?>
```